# In controller's action `params = params.merge({})` raises NoMethodError: undefined method `merge' for nil:NilClass

Tags: merge, parameters, ruby-on-rails-5, nomethoderror, actioncontroller

I am upgrading my **Ruby 2.3.1 / Rails 4.2.5.1** to **Rails 5.0.0.1** and I am encountering a strange error when running a controller spec for my following controller:

In my controller I have following code:

```
class Api::InboundSmsCallbackController < ActionController::Base
  include Api::SmsCallbackHelpers
  include Api::ServiceErrorHelpers

  # GET    /inbound_sms_callback/alert_acknowledgement(.:format)
  def alert_acknowledgement

    ....
    ...

    params.merge!({
      acknowledger_user_id: acknowledger_user.id,
      alert_id: alert.id,
      acknowledgement_time: sms_sent_at
    })

    begin
      creation_service = AcknowledgementAlert::CreationService.new(params)
    rescue ServiceError => se
      render json: json_hash, status: status
      return
    end

    ....
    ...

    render json: json_hash, status: 200
  end

end
```

After updating the bundle to use Rails 5, when I ran the controller code I got following warning:

> DEPRECATION WARNING: Method merge! is deprecated and will be removed
>   in Rails 5.1, as `ActionController::Parameters` no longer
>         inherits from hash. Using this deprecated behavior exposes potential security problems. If you continue to use this method you
>   may be
>         creating a security vulnerability in your app that can be exploited. Instead, consider using one of these documented methods
>   which are
>         not deprecated: http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.0.0.1/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html

To fix this I changed

```
    params.merge!({
      acknowledger_user_id: acknowledger_user.id,
      alert_id: alert.id,
      acknowledgement_time: sms_sent_at
    })
```

TO

```
    params = params.merge({
      acknowledger_user_id: acknowledger_user.id,
      alert_id: alert.id,
      acknowledgement_time: sms_sent_at
    })
```

and I am passing the params to my service class in following manner:

```
creation_service = AcknowledgementAlert::CreationService.new(params.to_unsafe_h)
```

But with that change when I run the spec example it fails with error saying

```
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `merge' for nil:NilClass
```

and the error trace points to the line where I made the change:

```
    params = params.merge({
      acknowledger_user_id: acknowledger_user.id,
      alert_id: alert.id,
      acknowledgement_time: sms_sent_at
    })
```

That is very weird because I tried printing `params` before that statement is evaluated and I am getting an object printed:

```
  >>>>>>>>>>>. params: <ActionController::Parameters {"message-timestamp"=>"2016-10-06 12:35:15 UTC", "msisdn"=>"919845128956", "text"=>"S3e9a6cE", "to"=>"12547836910", "controller"=>"api/inbound_sms_callback", "action"=>"alert_acknowledgement"} permitted: false>
```

Then why invoking `merge` on `params` is complaining about nil:NilClass.

I tried changing my updated code to

```
    ackn_params = params.merge({
      acknowledger_user_id: acknowledger_user.id,
      alert_id: alert.id,
      acknowledgement_time: sms_sent_at
    })

   creation_service = AcknowledgementAlert::CreationService.new(ackn_params.to_unsafe_h)
```

and it gets executed and my spec example passes.

I am not getting why then `params = params.merge` doesn't work.

Does anybody has any idea on what is causing this weird behaviour?

Another thing I tried is:

```
params = params

ackn_params = params.merge({
  acknowledger_user_id: acknowledger_user.id,
  alert_id: alert.id,
  acknowledgement_time: sms_sent_at
})
```

Now that fails with the same error

```
 undefined method `merge' for nil:NilClass
```

So it looks like reassignment to `params` is the root cause behind this. If this sounds correct then is there any specific reason why `params` cannot be reassigned because [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.0.0.1/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-merge) of `ActionController::Parameters#merge(other_hash)` method says

```
  Returns a new ActionController::Parameters with all keys from other_hash merges into current hash.
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think, this should help you:

```
params = params.permit(:values, :from, :params).to_h.merge({
      acknowledger_user_id: acknowledger_user.id,
      alert_id: alert.id,
      acknowledgement_time: sms_sent_at
})
```

Comment: Thanks. I am more concerned about why `params = params.merge` complains about params being `nil` when `params.merge` is evaluated. That's really puzzling.

Comment: @JiggneshhGohel

Answer (score 0):

Params is Nil. You cannot .merge .permit on something that is not there. Make sure params is being initialized as an object first.